# How to span both a row and column in React Native?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

**Question**
How do I utilize flexbox to have text take up both a row and column? I want the top left, top right, and bottom left of a square to fill with text.

**Flex Direction Column/Row Example:**

```
return <View style={[
            {flex:1 , flexDirection: 'column' // also tried row}
        ]}>
            <Text style={[
                flex:1,
                flexWrap: 'wrap',
                overflow: "visible",
            ]}>
                This is some text that I want to wrap right and then drop to the next row.
            </Text>
            <View style={
                {
                    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                    width: '25%',
                    height: '25%',
                },
            }>
            </View>
        </View>
}
```

**Result**
[image: example_image]

**Problem:**
If I place the flex direction to row the text will only span the column and the inverse is true for flex direction as column. How do I span the text around this item?

---

**Alignment Example:**

```
return <Text style={[
                flex:1,
                flexWrap: 'wrap',
                overflow: "visible",
            ]}>
                This is some text that I want to wrap right and then drop to the next row.
            </Text>
            <View style={
                {
                    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                    width: '25%',
                    height: '25%',
                },
            }>
            </View>
}
```

**Result**
[image: no_flex_direction_example]

**Problem**
The text still doesn't wrap to the next row or in its column.

Comment: Are you sure the project is building? There are some errors the way you've written these examples and sometimes react-native shows these types of errors only in the console, running an old version of the app.

Comment: @Auticcat These were just example snippets and there was an error via copy paste. But yes, the project builds with no issues.